# Autoregressive vs integrated time series model

Tags: terminology, autoregressive

An autoregressive series is of the form

> $$
> X_t = c + \varphi_1 X_{t-1} + \varphi_2 X_{t-2} + \cdots + \varepsilon_t
> $$

An integrated series is of the form

> $$
> (1-B)^d X_t = \varepsilon_t
> $$

However, it seems to me that this is just a special case of the autoregressive series with $\phi_k = (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}$ and $c=0$. Is this really the case? If so, why is worth naming?

For context: I can only find any mention of integrated models in ARIMA models, so I was wondering why they appear there but nowhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'I' in ARIMA stands for integrated!

And your second equation isn't exactly correct. Suppose we have
a process $ X_t $, and we define the following:

$$
Y_t := (1 - B)^d X_t
$$

where $ B $ is the backshift operator.

If $ Y_t $ is an ARMA(p, q) process, then $ X_t $ is said to be an ARIMA(p, d, q)
process.

It's not exactly a "special case" of AR because $ Y_t $ is required to be ARMA.

Comment: How is my second equation incorrect?

Comment: It suggests that what remains after differencing $ X_t $ is white noise, which is not necessarily true if $ X_t $ is ARIMA.

Comment: It's supposed to be the integrated series, which I thought would be ARIMA(0,d,0)?

Comment: No, in your equation the *integrated* series is $ X_t $. *After* differencing, it should become a stationary ARMA(p, q) process, of general p and q. $ \epsilon_t $ is generally used to represent a white noise series; here, it should be a general ARMA(p, q) series.

Comment: Isn't I(d) = ARIMA(0,d,0)? How would you write an integrated series?

Comment: Okay, so any time series can be integrated. It's not necessarily true that after differencing an integrated time series that it will have any kind of structure; the only guarantee that you have is that it will be stationary. Your notation implies that it'll be white noise after differencing, which is not true in general.